# How to calculate the difference between actual time and display countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, function, time

I would like to display the difference between two times.

The first time is the actual time that I can display through:

```
window.setInterval("timefunc()",1000);
    function timefunc(){
        d = new Date ();
        h = (d.getHours () < 10 ? '0' + d.getHours () : d.getHours ());
        m = (d.getMinutes () < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes () : d.getMinutes ());
        s = (d.getSeconds () < 10 ? '0' + d.getSeconds () : d.getSeconds ());

        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = 
        + h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
    }
```

Now I would like to extend this function. The second time is every day the same at 8pm.

Now for example it is 6:30pm. Here I would like to display the time left as a countdown. In this case something like: "Time left: 1:29:59". When the time is up there should be a reload of the page.

I`m totally new to Javascript and did not found any example somewhere.

I really would appreciate if there is someone who could help me out.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Please refer this link http://www.labs.mimmin.com/countdown/demos.php

Comment: hi, the problem is that I do not understand the code... how can I set the todays date at 8pm? in such examples it always will be set a complete date: 'var seconds = remaining.getSeconds('16 April, 2014 08:31:23');' How can I set this to "todays" time, somethink like that: ('dd, yyyy 20:00:00'); or this already correct?

Comment: `var dt = new Date(yyyy, mm, dd, HH, MM, SS);`

Comment: and what to do with that? where is the 8pm?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date object for 8:00 pm (20:00) today using:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(20,0,0,0);
```

To find the difference between two dates in milliseconds, simply subtract one from the other:

```
var ms = d - new Date();
```

To convert to hh:mm:ss:

```
var hours = ms / 3.6e6 | 0;
var mins  = (ms % 3.6e6) / 6e4 | 0;
var secs  = (ms % 6e4) / 1e3 | 0;
```

To padd single digit numbers:

```
function pad(n) {return (n<10? '0':'') + n;}
```

and format the output:

```
pad(hours) + ':' + pad(mins) + ':' + pad(secs);
```

Maybe you want the count down to tick over after 8 pm. In that case, just check if the current date is after 8 pm. If it is, just add one to the date of the 8 pm date object:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(20,0,0,0);
var now = new Date();

if (d < now) d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
```

So if *now* is after 8 pm (20:00), *d* is 8 pm tomorrow.

Comment: hello, this seems to answer my question. I would not like to tick over after 8pm. there should be a page reload. thanks for so far.

Comment: it does not display the time :( I added 'document.getElementById("left").innerHTML = 
+ pad(hours) + ':' + pad(mins) + ':' + pad(secs);' and a span into body.